# does this routine exist? until (while until true)

Tags: elisp-macros, libraries

I found myself needing this control loop and was very surprised not to find it in the standard library. Does it exist by some other name?

```
(defmacro until (form &optional guard)
  "Runs `while' on FORM until it is non-nil, returning the value.

A guard is provided which may cause the loop to exit early with nil."
  (let ((res (gensym "res")))
    `(let (,res)
       (while (and (not ,guard)
                   (not (setq ,res ,form))))
       ,res)))
```

Comment: It does in the form of a keyword in `cl-loop` macro, if that helps.

Comment: Related emacs-devel thread: [Why is there no `until' in elisp?](https://lists.gnu.org/r/emacs-devel/2018-10/msg00239.html).

Comment: It exists, because you just wrote it. ;-)